# How do I know which Systemverilog macros are defined when using Modelsim or Questasim?

Tags: system-verilog, modelsim, questasim

I'm using Questasim 10.4c to simulate a Systemverilog design that uses the `ifdef  compiler directive at a bunch of places. Example:

```
`ifdef FOR_SIMULATION_ONLY
<code>
`endif
```

After compiling, I haven't found any way to get Questasim to be able to tell me explicitly whether FOR_SIMULATION_ONLY has been defined, though. I've dug through the user guide and command reference manual and the closest thing I've found is putting a -E option in all my vlog compile statements and then examining the files created to see if FOR_SIMULATION_ONLY is defined. Can Questasim tell me, though, whether it's been defined without having to use the vlog -E method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no switch to do that. You can put in

```
`ifdef FOR_SIMULATION_ONLY
  $info("FOR_SIMULATION_ONLY defined");
`endif
```

and get a message at elaboration time.